# How to determine wether a geo point(latitude, longitude pair) lies on a line connecting two geo points

Tags: java, location

I am creating a java application that gives estimated time of arrival (eta) for a vehicle at next stops along it's route. 
vehicle sends it's current location(latitude and longitude) and a route it is following. 
Route is a poly line and it's end points are stops along that route.Each stop represented by a geopoint(latitude, longitude pair).
Also, route is from a set of known routes i.e. the location(latitude, longitude) of each stop along the route is already known. 
**I want to determine the eta for the vehical at next stops along its route.**
I have pre-calulated the time it takes to move from stop location A to stop location B along a route.(e.g consider a bus route).
So, once I get the current location, (it would be either a stop location or some location between two stop points along a route)
I can find out the distance from current location to the next stop. From that distance I can calculate the time it will take to 
reach the next stop and hence all other stops along the route by adding the pre calculated time for stops. Now, my question is

1. How to determine whether the current location(latitude and longitude) transmitted by vehical is actually along the route.
2. If 1)is true, how to determine between which two stop locations along the route the current location lies (thus I can calculate the distance from current location to the next stop location.)

If it were a Cartesian co-ordinate system it was easy to determine whether a point lies on a line connected by two end points.
How to do that for geo points(latitude, longitude pair). I have searched all over the web, there are methods to calculate the distance between 
two geopoints but did not find any method to determine whether a geopoint lies on a line between two geo points

Comment: I interpret your question to be a line on the surface of a square, and that you mean along the great circle? Because if it could be any circle, then the answer would always be yes.

Comment: If you have the formula to calculate the distance between two points, then one way to tell whether a point V is between points A and B is to add the distance from A to V and the distance from V to B.  If the result is the same as the distance from A to B, then you've got a straight line (or at least, part of a great circle).

Comment: (Typo, in my comment, I meant sphere, not square)

Comment: @ MrBackend. Yes.
The question I asked is a small part of a bigger problem I am trying to solve.
I know how to calculate the distance between two geo points.
So I thought if I could find out that the current location C of vehical is between stops A and B , I can find out the distance(and hence time)
to go from C to B and hence to subsequent stops along its route. I really don't know how to do that programmatic ally.
(Is there anything wrong with my approach to solve this problem? I am not able to think of any other approach at the moment.)
Note: I am new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Cartesian co-ordinate system it is easy to compose an equation of the line that crosses two points (as such line is unique possible). In case of sphere it is possible to draw several lines which cross two points on surface. Even more, in some cases it is possible to draw several lines with equal length through two points. So it is not surprising that there is not such API in popular GIS libraries (but specialized mathematical packages can contain this stuff).

1. Right way is already mentioned by [@David Wallace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652471/how-to-determine-wether-a-geo-pointlatitude-longitude-pair-lies-on-a-line-con#comment29182616_19652471)
2. Apply the rule above for each segment of your polyline. Then select the segment that is characterized by minimal deviation from expected distance between vehicle's location and endings of segment. This segment will be current part of route.

Returning to libraries: perhaps popular libraries are implemented with some approximation. For example, in case of not large city, Cartesian approximation can be used (I encountered such feature in [SUMO](http://www.dlr.de/ts/en/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-9883/16931_read-41000/). That tool is designed specifically for traffic simulation. And it uses flat 2D coordinates).